# Has this patent been granted and how do I contact the named inventor?

Tags: question

In reference to the patent: [US7925036](https://www.google.com/patents/US7925036)

Has this patent been granted and how do I contact the named inventor?

Answer (score 1):

The patent was granted vide issue notification dated 12 April 2011. Please refer 'grant issue notification' and 'combined declaration and power of attorney' at www.portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair for application No. 12/200695.

Direct communication address of first inventor **Peter M. Bouvier** is

**6005 HUGHES STREET,
SANDIEGO, CA 92115** .

Attempt can also be made through his attorney of

**PROCOPIO, CORY, HARGREAVES & SAVITCH LLP,
525 B STRRET,
SUITE 2200,
SANDIEGO, CA 92101-4469,
(619)238-1900**

However, in power of attorney the address reflects SUITE 2100.

Comment: This is a pretty good answer. I could be better if it were a bit better formatted to make it easier to read. Also, can you explain the word "vide"? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Dictionary meaning of vide :  /ˈvɪdeɪ,ˈviːdeɪ,ˈvʌɪdi/
verb
see; consult (used as an instruction in a text to refer the reader to a specified passage, book, author, etc., for further information).
"vide the comments cited in Schlosser" @ Eric Shain

Comment: Interesting, I’ve never come across the word, and I’ve been around awhile. The edits are very good.

Comment: @Eric Shain. Thanks for the encouraging words for an ab-initio.